# Knowing, without doing a restore, which IAPs have been purchased

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

My app has individual non-consumable in-app purchases for sale, plus a "bulk" IAP which contains all the other IAPs at a discounted price. Therefore, before allowing the user to purchase an IAP, I need to know which other IAPs they have already purchased. The only way I know of to get this info is to call restoreCompletedTransactions. But Apple has rejected my app, saying I'm not allowed to call restoreCompletedTransactions before displaying the Confirm In-App Purchase dialog. AFAIK this dialog appears when a purchase is attempted. So I'm stuck. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks!!

Comment: According to the [In-App Purchase Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), the IAP is only responsible for collecting payment. You are responsible for unlocking or delivering content, so maybe you can use whatever information you are using currently internally to determine whether to display this content to determine what they already own.

Comment: @Michael Lee, I meet the same problem, do you have any solution?

Comment: This was a year and a half ago, so this info may be dated, but I found there was no way to find out from the app store what purchases had been made. You have to keep track yourself on your own server.

Answer (score 2):

What does your app do once a purchase is made? Surely it sets a flag or 2 to allow additional content to work?
Can you not check for whats unlocked, then you'll know whats been bought.

If not, then simply store a value somewhere when a purchase is made.

Comment: Yes, I am remembering what purchases the user has made in NSUserDefaults. But that doesn't help - they may switch to another device.

Comment: You need to have a restore purchases button, so if they reinstall or change device, it'll perform the restoreCompletedTransactions method. It's not uncommon for Apple to reject apps that don't have a restore button lately.

Comment: I have a Restore button. The problem is if they havent' done a restore, and they try to purchase an item, and they have already purchased the bulk item which contains that item, I need to tell them they already own it and not perform the purchase. So I need a way to know, without doing a restore, which items they've purchased. (I tried doing a restore first, whenever the user tries to purchase, but apple rejected my app. They said a restore cannot occur before the Confirm In-App Purchase dialog is displayed.)

Comment: If you try and purchase an item you've already purchased before, the app store automatically tells you that you already have it and re-authorises it for free. So no need to check.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but you're not answering my question. I need to make sure the user doesnt' purchase an item that's included in another purchasable item.

Comment: Well you know within the app what's purchased. If a user installs on another device then it's up to them to hit the restore purchases button first before making more purchases.

Comment: If the user in effect purchased the same thing twice, I don't think they would be happy with that answer.

Comment: Well if apple won't let you call restoreCompletedTransactions before a purchase, then on a fresh install the only option is the restore button!

Comment: I was trying to find out if there are other options. One person suggested storing transactions on our own server. I may have to do that. Or give huge warnings about using the Restore button.

Comment: The easiest way would be an alert message when they attempt a purchase asking them to use the restore button if they've previously made a purchase. Although its not very pretty as it'll be rare that people change device then make another purchase.

Comment: Right, that's probably the best solution. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you couldnt make yourself clear about what you are trying to do. As I am trying to do the same thing let me explain.

When someone purchases a non-consumable IAP you give them some privileges.

In your case discounts, in my case some extra points.

When you dont know that it is the first purchase of the non-consumable IAP you will always give discounts when user press the buy button. You cant store it in NSUserDefaults or keychain because it wont help if user changes device.

So if user buys the IAP from a device, he gets discounts on that device, its cool but he can do this at every device he logs in with the same account. In order to prevent this you need to know if it is the first purchase or not.

Some can say that you should let him to get discounts. I dont know about what he is thinking but in my case I am giving the points for only once because he can make many points with just changing devices and that would be unfair...

Btw I came up with a solution for this but it is not very useful. You can make a gamecenter leaderboard called Pro Users and when someone buys your IAP you can give 100 points to that leaderboard. After that you can check the users score to see if he bought it already or not ...